# Subset relation ⊆ on all subsets of ℤ is a partial order, not a total order.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, order-theory, integers

I need to prove that the subset relation “⊆” on all subsets of ℤ is a partial order but not a total order. I'm not experienced in these kind of proofs and was hoping to see an example of an easier one so I could attempts other ones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember that the difference between a *partial* order and a *total* order is that in a partial order, you can have incomparable elements. Can you think of sets $A$ and $B$ such that $A\not\subseteq B$ and $B\not\subseteq A$?

---

To clarify: such an example will merely show that $(\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Z}), \subseteq)$ is *not* a *total* order. You still need to show that it *is* a partial order. To do this, you need to show that the following properties hold:

- $\subseteq$ is *transitive*: if $A\subseteq B\subseteq C$, then $A\subseteq C$.
- $\subseteq$ is *reflexive*: $A\subseteq A$.
- $\subseteq$ is *antisymmetric*: if $A\subseteq B$ and $B\subseteq A$, then $A=B$.

Although the proofs of these are short, they can seem odd at first glance. Let me give as an example the proof of transitivity:

> Suppose $A\subseteq B$ and $B\subseteq C$. I want to show $A\subseteq C$. So let $a\in A$; we need to show that $a\in C$. Since $A\subseteq B$, we know $a\in B$. And since $B\subseteq C$, every element of $B$ is an element of $C$; so $a\in C$. So we're done.

Does this make sense? If not, what is the sticking point? If so, can you do the other two?

Comment: Yes that makes sense. so how would you go about just proving partial order?

Comment: @sanic Do you understand my proof of transitivity? If so, can you see how to prove reflexivity and antisymmetry?

Comment: yes I get that, if I prove those 3 things those I'm only proving partial order. How do I prove not total order?

Comment: @sanic That's what the first paragraph of my answer addresses. If you can find $A, B$ such that $A\not\subseteq B$ and $B\not\subseteq A$, then you've shown that it is not a total order.

Comment: Gotcha. So a counterexample essentially?